# Why does my variable contain "2122" and not "2322"?

Tags: java, mutators, string-pool

This was a question on an exam. Luckily I picked the right answer, but I still can't see why it's right.

Consider this program:

```
class D {
  protected C c;
  public D(C c) {
    this.c = new C(c);
  }
  public C getC() {
    return c;
  }
  public void setC(C c) {
    this.c = c;
  }
}
class C {
  protected String s;
  public C(String s) {
    this.s = s;
  }
  public C(C c) {
    this(c.s);
  }
  public String getS() {
    return s;
  }
  public void setS(String s) {
    this.s = s;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    C c1 = new C("1");
    C c2 = new C("2");
    D[] d = {
      new D(c1), new D(c1), new D(c2), new D(c2)
    };
    d[0] = d[3];
    c1.setS("3");
    String r = "";
    for (D i: d) {
      r += i.getC().getS();
    }
    System.out.println(r);
  }

}
```

It'll print `2122`. I would expect `2322` however (I'm clearly wrong when you run the code). My reasoning behind that:

In the third line of the main method, four instances of `D` get initialized.
The constructor of `D` makes a new instance of `C`. An instance of `C` has a `String` variable which points somewhere to a spot in the memory. Now the instance variable `c`, let's call it `c3`, of the object in `d[1]` has a instance variable (type `String`), let's call it `s3`, pointing to the same memory as the `String s1`, variable of `c1`.

So when we change `s1`, I'd expect the value of `s3` also to change, since it's pointing to the same spot in the memory.

On a side note, if you change the constructor of `D`, see below, you'll get `2322` instead. Which I'd expect, since now the variable `c3` in `d[1]` is pointing directly towards the memory location of `c1`.

```
public D(C c) {
  this.c = c;
}
```

My thoughts so far on the explanation (could be wrong):

1. When initializing the instance variable `s1`/`s3`, new `String` objects get made (so far I assumed they were pointing towards `"1"` in the `String` pool, since the constructor of `C` makes it look that way)
2. When changing `s1`, it's pointer will be redirected towards `"3"` in the `String` pool. Rather than `"1"` becoming `"3"` in the pool.

Could anyone explain this behaviour? What are the errors in my (faulty) reasoning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: @njzk2 it's not a duplicate. But that helps understanding the result of this program.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `So when we change s1, I'd expect the value of s3 also to change, since it's pointing to the same spot in the memory.` To me the OP is confused by the way variables are passed and referred to in java.

Comment: @njzk2 yes. And providing that link as the only answer would not probably suffice to explain this behavior. That's why I provided an answer to explain this in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to `String` pooling at all. Main answer: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1065197)

That's because `D` creates a new instance of `C` based on `C#c`. This mean that the instance of `D#c` is not the same instance as parameter `C` passed in constructor `D`, thus modifying that instance won't affect the current instance in `D#c`.

---

Re explaining all this in nice terms.

Here's what you're testing:

```
class Surprise {
    String item;
    public Surprise(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    //this is called copy constructor
    //because you receive an object from the same class
    //and copy the values of the fields into the current instance
    //this way you can have a "copy" of the object sent as parameter
    //and these two object references are not tied by any mean
    public Surprise(Surprise another) {
        //here you just copy the value of the object reference of another#item
        //into this#item
        this.item = another.item;
    }
}

class Box {
    Surprise surprise;
    public Box(Surprise surprise) {
        //here you create a totally new instance of Surprise
        //that is not tied to the parameter surprise by any mean
        this.surprise = new Surprise(surprise);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Surprise surprise1 = new Surprise("1");
        Surprise surprise2 = new Surprise("2");
        Box[] boxes = {
            new Box(surprise1),
            new Box(surprise1),
            new Box(surprise2),
            new Box(surprise2)
        };
        boxes[0] = boxes[3];
        //you update surprise1 state
        //but the state of Box#surprise in the boxes that used surprise1
        //won't get affected because it is not the same object reference
        surprise1.item = "3";
        //print everything...
        System.out.println("Boxes full of surprises");
        //this code does the same as the printing above
        for (Box box : boxes) {
            System.out.print(box.surprise.item);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer first of all. I know the general idea of pass by value/reference. This example would make sense to me if the constructor in Surprise would make a new String i.e.: this.item=new String(another.item), instead of re-using the same one of 'another'. I can see why it are different instances of Surprise, but I have trouble seeing why there would be different Strings.

Comment: @flisk because you only copy the value of the reference of the String. So, then you update `surprise1#item` and affects only to that variable. The same could happen with `int`, `Integer` or even a mutable class because you associate `surprise1#item` with a totally new reference.

Comment: Ah, so basically, suprise1#item changes it's pointer?

Also intersesting, put System.out.println(d[1].getC().getS()==c1.s); the line after d[0]=d[3]. There you can see, the strings are still the  same(just before the change), because it prints true.

Comment: Ok nice, I think I fully understand it now. I've replaced all String with StringBuffer and changed c1 this way: c1.setS(c1.s.replace(0, 1, "3")); and the program did what I expected. Because StringBuffer is mutable, it doesn't need to make a new instance (i.e. change pointer) when it's value is changed. This way it printed "2322". Thanks!

Comment: @flisk note that you're modifying the state. If you use `c1.s = new StringBuffer("3");` then this will print "2122" again. Again, this is about passing by value. And if you use `new` keyword it won't matter if your object is immutable or not.

Comment: Yes, that's why I used a mutator method. Using 'new' creates a new object. When that happens, the pointer associated with c1 would change towards the new object's storage adress in the memory. The pointer assosiated with the String of d[1] would still be pointing at the storage adress of unchanged object "1", so you'd get "2122".
I've learned alot from this question :D

Comment: @flisk now you reflect that you understood this. Cool!